# Java MQEnvironment static properties

Tags: java, ibm-mq

This code sends the message to Q. MQEnvironment static values are set . But MQEnvironment  is **not referenced** anywhere in the manager. Then how the properties (hostname, channel,port,CCSID) are provided to connect to MQ?

```
    MQEnvironment.hostname ="10.XX.XXX.XX";

    MQEnvironment.channel = "SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN";

    MQEnvironment.port = 1415;

    MQEnvironment.CCSID = 819;

    System.out.println("connecting MQQueueManager...");
    try {
        MQQueueManager manager = new MQQueueManager("SXX");

        MQQueue queue = null;

        int openOptions = MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT; //MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF |

        queue = manager.accessQueue("Q_NAME",
                                            openOptions,
                                            null, null, null);
        // send message
        MQMessage sendMessage = new MQMessage();

        sendMessage.writeObject("TEST MESSAGE@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
        MQPutMessageOptions pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions();

        queue.put(sendMessage, pmo);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MQQueueManager object checks to see if those values have been set in the MQEnvironment class before it makes a connection to the queue manager.

Also, do NOT use the SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN channel as (1) it is against best practices and (2) it is a SYSTEM object that is ONLY to be used by the queue manager.  Simply create or have the MQAdmin create a SVRCONN channel for you.  i.e. TEST.CHL

Comment: Is there a way to set them directly in MQQueueManager.java?

Comment: Set what?  Channel name, hostname & port #?  Don't use MQEnvironment class as it is not thread safe.  Put the information in a Hashtable and pass it to MQQueueManager class.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34628283/java-program-to-connect-wmq-with-user-id-instead-of-channel/34642355#34642355

Answer (score 1):

MQEnvironment has public static class variables (kind of global constants).  The MQQueueManager object uses these values if they are set.
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.mq.java.doc%2Fcom%2Fibm%2Fmq%2FMQEnvironment.html