# Java program to connect WMQ with User Id instead of channel

Tags: ibm-mq

I have the requirement like connecting MQ with userid instead of channel.

I have tried with setting user id and password without chanel to MQEnvironment class but got the below exception.

```
com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2540;AMQ9520: Channel not defined remotely. [3=].
```

Please guide me, is it possible to write java client to connect MQ with user id instead of channel.

Comment: Please could you explain what you are thinking by saying "user id instead of channel"... In MQ the UserId is a different concept to a Channel.

Do you mean you want the userid used for authentication to be one specified by the application - rather than the MCA User id defined on the MQ ServerConn Channel?

Comment: Thanks Calanais for Reply. Here user id is a member of a group. This group authenticates MQ objects. Correct me, if I am wrong

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 ways for an MQ application to connect to a queue manager:  bindings and client mode.

- Bindings mode means that your MQ application is running on the SAME
  server as the queue manager.  Hence, the MQI calls will not use
  network resources.
- Client mode means that your MQ application can run on any server and
  it will use network resources when it issues MQI calls.  For the
  MQCONN call, besides the queue manager name, you will also need the
  hostname/IP address, port # and channel name.

In either case, your MQ application should be supplying its user credentials (UserID & Password).

Finally, do NOT use the MQEnvironment class.  It is far, far better to use a HashTable and pass it to the queue manager constructor class. i.e.

```
Hashtable<String, Object> mqht = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
mqht.put(CMQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, channelName);
mqht.put(CMQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, hostName);
mqht.put(CMQC.PORT_PROPERTY, new Integer(portNumber));
mqht.put(CMQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, userID);
mqht.put(CMQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, password);
try
{
   MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qMgrName, mqht);
   System.out.println("Successfully connected to "+ qMgrName);
}
catch (com.ibm.mq.MQException mqex)
{
   System.out.println("MQException cc=" +mqex.completionCode + " : rc=" + mqex.reasonCode);
}
```

Comment: Just to add a point, it is useless for an application to provide credentials if the MCAUser property is set (is not blank) for the SVRCONN channel used by the client. As the value of MCAUser will be used for authentication and authorization.

Comment: The channel's MCAUser is never used for authentication.  Also, whether you are using a 3rd party security exit for authentication or MQ v8 authentication, all applications should be supplying user credentials and stop the use of setting a value in MCAUser.  Hopefully, IBM will depreciate the MCAUser attribute in future versions of MQ.

Comment: Thanks Roger. This information is sufficient to understand MQ CONN calls.

Comment: @nitgeek please note that in MQ v8 and later if you have CONNAUTH CHKCLNT(OPTIONAL) or higher and ADOPTCTX(YES), if a user passes a valid username and password MQ will adopt this user and will override the MCAUSER value of the SVRCONN for OAM checks.  Even in MQ 7.1 and 7.5 CHLAUTH rules can override the MCAUSER value of the SVRCONN channel for OAM checks.