# how to read MQ messages using java without deleting message from the queue

Tags: java, ibm-mq

When I execute my below code, it will read data from MQ on the console and then delete all the data from the queue. I don't want my data to be deleted from the queue while reading from MQ. I want to make it parameterize and also wants to write the data to excel. Can anybody please help me out from this. Below is my code that I am using.

```
public class MQReadJava
{
    private MQQueueManager _queueManager = null;
    public int port = 1416;
    public String hostname = "xyz";
    public String channel = "SYSTEM.ABC.123";
    public String qManager = "ABC.BAW";
    public String inputQName = "MYQUEUE";

    public MQReadJava()
    {
        super(); 
    }

    private void init(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        // Set up MQ environment

        MQEnvironment.hostname = hostname;
        MQEnvironment.channel = channel;
        MQEnvironment.port = port;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        MQReadJava readQ = new MQReadJava();
        try
        {
            readQ.init(args);
            readQ.selectQMgr();
            readQ.read();
        }

        catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
        {
            System.exit(1);
        }
        catch (MQException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    private void selectQMgr() throws MQException
    {
        _queueManager = new MQQueueManager(qManager);
    }

    private void read() throws MQException
    {
        int openOptions = MQC.MQOO_INQUIRE + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING + MQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED;

        //int   openOptions = MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF | MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;

        MQQueue queue = _queueManager.accessQueue( inputQName,
        openOptions,
        null, // default q manager
        null, // no dynamic q name
        null ); // no alternate user id

        System.out.println("MQRead is now connected.\n");
        int depth = queue.getCurrentDepth();
        System.out.println("Current depth: " + depth + "\n");

        if (depth == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        MQGetMessageOptions getOptions = new MQGetMessageOptions();
        getOptions.options = MQC.MQGMO_NO_WAIT + MQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING + 
        MQC.MQGMO_CONVERT;

        while(true)
        {
            MQMessage message = new MQMessage();
            try
            {
                queue.get(message, getOptions);
                byte[] b = new byte[message.getMessageLength()];
                message.readFully(b);
                System.out.println(new String(b));
                message.clearMessage();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("IOException during GET: " + e.getMessage());
                break;
            }
            catch (MQException e)
            {
                if (e.completionCode == 2 && e.reasonCode == MQException.MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE) {
                    if (depth > 0)
                    {
                        System.out.println("All messages read.");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("GET Exception: " + e);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        queue.close();
        _queueManager.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to directly add a comment to JoshMc, so I am adding a separate message here. It is better to use com.ibm.mq.constants.MQConstants instead of com.ibm.mq.MQC class because MQC is deprecated since 2008

Comment: @Hakan54 thank you for the comment, as I was just attempting to help him fix the sample he provided, I used the syntax he presented as it matches the rest of what is program has.  He did not mention which MQ classes for Java version he is using, so far all I know he may be using a old out of date version that does not have `MQConstants`

Answer (score 5):

> Below is my code that I am using.

:)  You downloaded my MQRead program.  If you don't want it to do a destructive MQGET then you need to update the code to do a browse (see JoshMc's comments).  Why didn't you download my MQBrowse program?  Finally, please start reading the [MQ Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q023721_.htm) as it contains lots & lots of information for beginners to IBM MQ.

---

Update: You should not use MQEnvironment class as it is not thread safe.  Put the connection information in a Hashtable.  See here for an example: 
[Java program to connect WMQ with User Id instead of channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34628283/java-program-to-connect-wmq-with-user-id-instead-of-channel/34642355#34642355)

Comment: Hi @Roger, I'm getting **MQJE001: Completion Code 1, Reason 2110** when I try to run the above program. On my R&D, I got to know that, it's because of format issue. How can I set MQMD to MQSTR in my Java program?

Comment: You don't set MQMD to MQSTR, you set the Format field of the MQMD to CMQC.MQFMT_STRING.

Answer (score 2):

In order to not delete messages from the queue you need to browse the queue, this would be accomplished by updating your openOptions and getOptions as follows:

```
int openOptions = MQC.MQOO_INQUIRE + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING +  MQC.MQOO_BROWSE;
```

and

```
getOptions.options = MQC.MQGMO_NO_WAIT + MQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING + MQC.MQGMO_CONVERT + MQC.MQGMO_BROWSE_NEXT;
```

---

Checkout this great list of sample IBM MQ Classes for Java applications on Capitalware's website: [Sample IBM MQ Java Code](http://www.capitalware.com/mq_code_java.html)