# Two simple IBM MQ client tests write to MQ queue - why does one work, but, NOT the other?

Tags: java-8, ibm-mq

I'm running two(2) client tests.

Presumably they should both work.  But, one does not, and I do not know why.

***(1) This one works...***

```
package aaa.bbb.ccc;

import com.ibm.mq.MQEnvironment;
import com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager;
import com.ibm.mq.MQQueue;
import com.ibm.mq.MQMessage;
import com.ibm.mq.MQPutMessageOptions;
import com.ibm.mq.constants.CMQC;
import com.ibm.mq.constants.MQConstants;

public class MQCheck {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        int openOptions = CMQC.MQOO_INQUIRE | CMQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF | MQConstants.MQOO_OUTPUT;
        MQEnvironment.hostname = "localhost";
        MQEnvironment.port = 1414;
        MQEnvironment.channel = "DEV.APP.SVRCONN";
        MQEnvironment.properties.put(CMQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, "admin");
        MQEnvironment.properties.put(CMQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "passw0rd");          
        MQEnvironment.properties.put(CMQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, CMQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES);
        MQQueueManager qMgr;
        qMgr = new MQQueueManager("QM1");
        MQQueue destQueue = qMgr.accessQueue("mylocalqueue", openOptions);
        MQMessage hello_world = new MQMessage();
        hello_world.writeUTF("Blah...blah...bleah...test message no.1...!");
        MQPutMessageOptions pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions();
        destQueue.put(hello_world, pmo);
        destQueue.close();
        qMgr.disconnect();
        System.out.println("------------------------success...");            
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

***(2) This one does NOT work...***

```
package aaa.bbb.ccc;

import com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnection;
import com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory;
import com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession;
import com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.WMQConstants;
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.QueueSession;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

public class MQCheck3 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

    Connection qconn = null;
    QueueSession qsess = null;
    MQSession mqsess;
    Queue queue = null;

    try {
        MQQueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setHostName("localhost");
        connectionFactory.setChannel("DEV.APP.SVRCONN");//communications link
        connectionFactory.setPort(1414);
        connectionFactory.setQueueManager("QM1");
        connectionFactory.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
        connectionFactory.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.CAPABILITY_USERNAME_PASSWORD, true);
        connectionFactory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.USERID, "admin");
        connectionFactory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.PASSWORD, "passw0rd");            
        qconn = (MQQueueConnection) connectionFactory.createConnection();
        qconn = connectionFactory.createQueueConnection();
        qconn.start();
        mqsess = (MQSession) qconn.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE); //.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        queue = mqsess.createQueue("mylocalqueue");
        TextMessage textMessage = mqsess.createTextMessage("Bleah...bleah...blech...test message no.2...!");
        MessageProducer mc = mqsess.createProducer(queue);
        mc.send(textMessage, 0, 0, 0);
        System.out.println("------------------------success...");  
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
        qsess.close();
        qconn.close();
        } catch (JMSException e) {
        System.err.print(e);
        }
    }
    }
}
```

NOTE: 
Running the code in (2) gets the following exception...

```
Exception: com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSSecurityException: JMSWMQ2013: The security authentication was not valid that was supplied for QueueManager 'QM1' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'localhost(1414)'.
Please check if the supplied username and password are correct on the QueueManager to which you are connecting.
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSSecurityException: JMSWMQ2013: The security authentication was not valid that was supplied for QueueManager 'QM1' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'localhost(1414)'.
Please check if the supplied username and password are correct on the QueueManager to which you are connecting.
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:514)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:214)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.<init>(WMQConnection.java:408)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:6398)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:5740)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl._createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:293)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:234)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.createCommonConnection(MQConnectionFactory.java:6016)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:111)
    at aaa.bbb.ccc.MQCheck3.main(MQCheck3.java:35)
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED').
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:202)
    ... 8 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at aaa.bbb.ccc.MQCheck3.main(MQCheck3.java:48)
```

***QUESTION: can anyone explain to me why the 2nd example does not work?:  ***

-Is there something that is incorrect and/or missing from the code that would enable it to work?

***FYI - running MQ server from Docker image:***

C:>docker exec mq dspmqver

```
C:\>docker exec mq dspmqver
Name:        IBM MQ
Version:     9.0.3.0
Level:       p903-L170517.DE
BuildType:   IKAP - (Production)
Platform:    IBM MQ for Linux (x86-64 platform)
Mode:        64-bit
O/S:         Linux 4.9.31-moby
InstName:    Installation1
InstDesc:
Primary:     Yes
InstPath:    /opt/mqm
DataPath:    /var/mqm
MaxCmdLevel: 903
LicenseType: Developer

C:\>
```

***pom.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>aaa.bbb.ccc</groupId>
    <artifactId>mqcheck</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>mqcheck</name>
    <description>mqcheck</description>

    <properties>
    <mq.version>8.0.0.2</mq.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ibm.mq</groupId>
        <artifactId>fscontext</artifactId>
        <version>${mq.version}</version>
    </dependency>          
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ibm.mq</groupId>
        <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
        <version>${mq.version}</version>
    </dependency>        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ibm.mq</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.ibm.mq</artifactId>
        <version>${mq.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ibm.mq</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.ibm.mqjms</artifactId>
        <version>${mq.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ibm.mq</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.jmqi</artifactId>
        <version>${mq.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ibm.mq</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.headers</artifactId>
        <version>${mq.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ibm.mq</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.commonservices</artifactId>
        <version>${mq.version}</version>
    </dependency>    
    </dependencies>

    <build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
            <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>              
    </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

***as per the suggestion in the post below (thx, joshmc),  here is the AMQERR01.log***
it appears to provide a clue... -now, the quest to determine how to I unblock the 'admin' user   :-)

```
----- cmqxrmsa.c : 1347 -------------------------------------------------------
08/11/17 17:32:09 - Process(1847.6) User(root) Program(amqrmppa)
            Host(bd069b8075db) Installation(Installation1)
            VRMF(9.0.3.0) QMgr(QM1)
            Time(2017-08-11T17:32:09.967Z)

AMQ9776: Channel was blocked by userid

EXPLANATION:
The inbound channel 'DEV.APP.SVRCONN' was blocked from address '172.17.0.1'
because the active values of the channel were mapped to a userid which should
be blocked. The active values of the channel were 'MCAUSER(admin)
CLNTUSER(admin)'.
ACTION:
Contact the systems administrator, who should examine the channel
authentication records to ensure that the correct settings have been
configured. The ALTER QMGR CHLAUTH switch is used to control whether channel
authentication records are used. The command DISPLAY CHLAUTH can be used to
query the channel authentication records.
----- cmqxrmsa.c : 1347 -------------------------------------------------------
```

***running following command (as suggested)...***

```
C:\>docker exec --tty --interactive mq runmqsc
5724-H72 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 1994, 2017.
Starting MQSC for queue manager QM1.
```

***DIS CHL(DEV.APP.SVRCONN) MCAUSER***

```
DIS CHL(DEV.APP.SVRCONN) MCAUSER
     1 : DIS CHL(DEV.APP.SVRCONN) MCAUSER
AMQ8414: Display Channel details.
   CHANNEL(DEV.APP.SVRCONN)                CHLTYPE(SVRCONN)
   MCAUSER(app)
       :
```

***DISPLAY CHLAUTH(DEV.APP.SVRCONN) MATCH(RUNCHECK) ALL ADDRESS(172.17.0.1)***

```
DISPLAY CHLAUTH(DEV.APP.SVRCONN) MATCH(RUNCHECK) ALL ADDRESS(172.17.0.1) CLNTUSER('admin')
     5 : DISPLAY CHLAUTH(DEV.APP.SVRCONN) MATCH(RUNCHECK) ALL ADDRESS(172.17.0.1) CLNTUSER('admin')
AMQ8878: Display channel authentication record details.
   CHLAUTH(DEV.APP.SVRCONN)                TYPE(ADDRESSMAP)
   DESCR( )                                CUSTOM( )
   ADDRESS(*)                              USERSRC(CHANNEL)
   CHCKCLNT(ASQMGR)                        ALTDATE(2017-08-11)
   ALTTIME(19.23.31)
```

***DIS QMGR CONNAUTH***

```
DIS QMGR CONNAUTH
     1 : DIS QMGR CONNAUTH
AMQ8408: Display Queue Manager details.
   QMNAME(QM1)                             CONNAUTH(DEV.AUTHINFO)
```

***DIS AUTHINFO(DEV.AUTHINFO)***

```
DIS AUTHINFO(DEV.AUTHINFO)
     2 : DIS AUTHINFO(DEV.AUTHINFO)
AMQ8566: Display authentication information details.
   AUTHINFO(DEV.AUTHINFO)                  AUTHTYPE(IDPWOS)
   ADOPTCTX(YES)                           DESCR( )
   CHCKCLNT(REQDADM)                       CHCKLOCL(OPTIONAL)
   FAILDLAY(1)                             AUTHENMD(OS)
   ALTDATE(2017-08-14)                     ALTTIME(13.57.29)
```

***DISPLAY CHLAUTH(DEV.APP.SVRCONN) all***

```
DISPLAY CHLAUTH(DEV.APP.SVRCONN) all
     1 : DISPLAY CHLAUTH(DEV.APP.SVRCONN) all
AMQ8878: Display channel authentication record details.
   CHLAUTH(DEV.APP.SVRCONN)                TYPE(ADDRESSMAP)
   DESCR( )                                CUSTOM( )
   ADDRESS(*)                              USERSRC(CHANNEL)
   CHCKCLNT(ASQMGR)                        ALTDATE(2017-08-16)
   ALTTIME(13.43.26)
```

***DISPLAY CHLAUTH(*) all***

```
DISPLAY CHLAUTH(*) all
     2 : DISPLAY CHLAUTH(*) all
AMQ8878: Display channel authentication record details.
   CHLAUTH(DEV.ADMIN.SVRCONN)              TYPE(USERMAP)
   DESCR(Allows admin user to connect via ADMIN channel)
   CUSTOM( )                               ADDRESS( )
   CLNTUSER(admin)                         USERSRC(CHANNEL)
   CHCKCLNT(ASQMGR)                        ALTDATE(2017-08-16)
   ALTTIME(13.43.26)
AMQ8878: Display channel authentication record details.
   CHLAUTH(DEV.ADMIN.SVRCONN)              TYPE(BLOCKUSER)
   DESCR(Allows admins on ADMIN channel)   CUSTOM( )
   USERLIST(nobody)                        WARN(NO)
   ALTDATE(2017-08-16)                     ALTTIME(13.43.26)
AMQ8878: Display channel authentication record details.
   CHLAUTH(DEV.APP.SVRCONN)                TYPE(ADDRESSMAP)
   DESCR( )                                CUSTOM( )
   ADDRESS(*)                              USERSRC(CHANNEL)
   CHCKCLNT(ASQMGR)                        ALTDATE(2017-08-16)
   ALTTIME(13.43.26)
AMQ8878: Display channel authentication record details.
   CHLAUTH(MY.ADMIN.SVRCONN)               TYPE(ADDRESSMAP)
   DESCR( )                                CUSTOM( )
   ADDRESS(127.0.0.1)                      USERSRC(CHANNEL)
   CHCKCLNT(ASQMGR)                        ALTDATE(2017-08-11)
   ALTTIME(20.17.14)
AMQ8878: Display channel authentication record details.
   CHLAUTH(MY.ADMIN.SVRCONN)               TYPE(BLOCKUSER)
   DESCR( )                                CUSTOM( )
   USERLIST(*NOBODY)                       WARN(NO)
   ALTDATE(2017-08-11)                     ALTTIME(20.17.51)
AMQ8878: Display channel authentication record details.
   CHLAUTH(SYSTEM.ADMIN.SVRCONN)           TYPE(ADDRESSMAP)
   DESCR(Default rule to allow MQ Explorer access)
   CUSTOM( )                               ADDRESS(*)
   USERSRC(CHANNEL)                        CHCKCLNT(ASQMGR)
   ALTDATE(2017-08-03)                     ALTTIME(17.22.22)
AMQ8878: Display channel authentication record details.
   CHLAUTH(SYSTEM.*)                       TYPE(ADDRESSMAP)
   DESCR(Default rule to disable all SYSTEM channels)
   CUSTOM( )                               ADDRESS(*)
   USERSRC(NOACCESS)                       WARN(NO)
   ALTDATE(2017-08-03)                     ALTTIME(17.22.22)
AMQ8878: Display channel authentication record details.
   CHLAUTH(*)                              TYPE(ADDRESSMAP)
   DESCR(Back-stop rule - Blocks everyone)
   CUSTOM( )                               ADDRESS(*)
   USERSRC(NOACCESS)                       WARN(NO)
   ALTDATE(2017-08-16)                     ALTTIME(13.43.26)
AMQ8878: Display channel authentication record details.
   CHLAUTH(*)                              TYPE(BLOCKUSER)
   DESCR(Default rule to disallow privileged users)
   CUSTOM( )                               USERLIST(*MQADMIN)
   WARN(NO)                                ALTDATE(2017-08-03)
   ALTTIME(17.22.22)
```

Comment: Using docker image...:    C:\>docker exec mq dspmqver
Name:        IBM MQ
Version:     9.0.3.0
Level:       p903-L170517.DE
BuildType:   IKAP - (Production)
Platform:    IBM MQ for Linux (x86-64 platform)
Mode:        64-bit
O/S:         Linux 4.9.31-moby
InstName:    Installation1
InstDesc:
Primary:     Yes
InstPath:    /opt/mqm
DataPath:    /var/mqm
MaxCmdLevel: 903
LicenseType: Developer

C:\>

Comment: using 8.0.0.2 dependency jars with "test client"....

Comment: by all "appearances" it appears they are using the same queue manager, same channel, and same userid.  from the error message in the AMQERR01.log, I wondering whether there is a difference in how the two api's handle authentication(?)...

Comment: Hi JoshMc:  It took a 'minute' to track down how to run the commands... You can let me know if I'm doing it incorrectly - see above

Comment: posted the results above. thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED')` can be caused by quite a few issues.

IBM Support Technote "[WMQ 7.1 / 7.5 / 8.0 / 9.0 queue manager RC 2035 MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED or AMQ4036 or JMSWMQ2013 when using client connection as an MQ Administrator](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21577137)" has a good write up on diagnosing and resolving issues like this.

If you want more specific help, to start with please provide the following details by editing and adding them to your question.

1. Version of IBM MQ Classes for JMS used by the client application.
2. Version of IBM MQ installed on the IBM MQ queue manager
3. Errors in the queue manager's AMQERR01.LOG that happen at the same time as the error you receive in the IBM MQ Classes for JMS client application.

---

Based on the error you have in the `AMQERR01.LOG` you have a `CHLAUTH` rule that is blocking you.  Run the following command to see which rule this is:

```
DISPLAY CHLAUTH(DEV.APP.SVRCONN) MATCH(RUNCHECK) ALL ADDRESS(172.17.0.1) CLNTUSER('admin')
```

If it is the default rule that blocks MQ administrative users from connecting, then this is a good thing from a security standpoint.  It is much better to have an application connect to the queue manager as a USERID that is low privileged and does not have MQ administrative authority.  To do this you need to grant the user authority to connect to the queue manager as well as to `PUT` or `GET` from the queues required.

---

After looking at the output so far I think what is happening is this.

1. The IBM MQ Classes for Java program is not actually authenticating as the admin user and is being defaulted to the MCAUSER(app) on the SVRCONN channel which is not a MQ Administrative user so does not get blocked.  The issue is that the `MQEnvironment.properties` is meant to hold the value of a Hash table of properties not individual properties.  Check out @Roger's answer to "[Java program to connect WMQ with User Id instead of channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34628283/java-program-to-connect-wmq-with-user-id-instead-of-channel/34642355#34642355)" for examples of using the Hashtable which is thread safe compared to the MQEnvironment which is not.  But in fixing this issue the IBM MQ Classes for Java app should be blocked the same as the JMS app.
2. The IBM MQ Classes for JMS program is properly authenticating as the admin user and ADOPTCTX(YES) is set and the admin user is a MQ Administrative user so is blocked by the following default CHLAUTH rule:

   ```
    CHLAUTH(*)                              TYPE(BLOCKUSER)
    DESCR(Default rule to disallow privileged users)
    CUSTOM( )                               USERLIST(*MQADMIN)
    WARN(NO)
   ```

Please validate by running the following:

```
DIS QMGR CONNAUTH
```

Then run the following command replacing the value `SYSTEM.DEFAULT.AUTHINFO.IDPWOS` with the value found in output of the above command if it is different:

```
DIS AUTHINFO(SYSTEM.DEFAULT.AUTHINFO.IDPWOS)
```

Note I'm not sure why the `RUNCHECK` is not returning the `BLOCKUSER` rule, I don't have a 9.0.3 to try this on but with a similar `ADDRESSMAP` rule to the one that is being returned for you I still get the `BLOCKUSER` rule on both 8.0.0.5 and 8.0.0.6.

Comment: Thx JoshMc! I'll give your suggestions a try sometime today(Monday), and let you know the results.

Comment: @sairn The results are consistent with what I suggested. So if you FIX your IBM MQ Classes for Java app it will fail as well. The reason the IBM MQ Classes for JMS application is failing is because the admin user is an administrative user which is blocked by the default CHLAUTH rule.

Comment: @sairn I am interested in understanding why your RUNCHECK does not return the block rule, could you run the two commands `DISPLAY CHLAUTH(DEV.APP.SVRCONN) all` and `DISPLAY CHLAUTH(*) all` and add the output to your question?  You can mask out anything that you do not want to share, ex: IP addresses, usernames, etc.

Comment: sure.  will do on Wednesday a.m. (EST).    I'll post the results and look forward to your thoughts on same.  Thx, Josh

Comment: Hi JoshMc - ran and posted the results above.  look forward to your comments. thx!

Comment: If you added `CLNTUSER(admin)` to the `RUNCHECK` it should show the block.  Sorry for the the long delay in responding.