# How to connect remote queue manager (Websphere MQ) from Java application

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

I/m trying to connect remote queue manager from my Java code.

I have host name, port number, channel, Queue manager name and queue name to connect the remote mq.

So my questions is...

Do we need to create a new queue manager and queue in local and then do Java configuration in code to connect remote mq?

I see MQSample.java has no local queue creation code, which was provided by IBM websphere mq.

When i try to access the host and port using telnet...it works showing blank cmd and. So I guess no connection problem to that remote host.

Please show some examples to connect remote mq using Java. I tried looking IBM MQ tutorial also.

Comment: @Roger posted a good sample that shows how to specify the hostname, port, channel, to a IBM MQ classes for Java application on the question "[Java program to connect WMQ with User Id instead of channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34628283/java-program-to-connect-wmq-with-user-id-instead-of-channel/34642355#34642355)"

Comment: Also note that you tagged this with [jms] but the Sample you reference is not using the IBM MQ classes for JMS, it is just a IBM MQ classes for Java application.